# Insert some croatian letters in to mysql databse using spring hibernate

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, internationalization

I have written hibernate query to save data in a mysql data table. UTF-8 is used inside code. The letter č is inserted into table as ?. I read several threads regarding this issue and tried following solutions.

Adding following line to the end of the jdbc url

```
?useEncoding=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8"
```

Adding following lines to the hibernate-config.xml file
**

```
"<prop key="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding" >utf8</prop>
<prop key="hibernate.connection.charSet">utf8</pop>"
```

**

And also I have set the charset to utf8.

None of above didn't work. Are there any solution to resolve this issue?

Comment: what database do you use?

Comment: @Lev ...... Database is MySQL

Comment: try to connect to your database like this: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf8

Comment: I tried it now. Still the issue is there.

Comment: You have to work separately i.e : testing the `database `if you can insert into database directly using the mysql interface ? secondly try to sysout.print one string that contain `č` in the server side. this will help you to find where do you stack.

Comment: Thank you everybody. Problem is solved by conencting to the database like this. jdbc\:mysql://localhost:3306/${SERVER_DB_NAME}?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&characterSetResults=utf8